# Getting connection refused in docker

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, proxy, docker

I am using ubuntu 16.04. After installing `docker`, when I run `docker pull hello-world`, I am getting this error :

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 35.169.231.249:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I think the problem may be due to the proxy setting of my connection. I am using college LAN and it uses proxy setting for hostname and port. 
I am getting problem only here in `docker`. Rest of the thing is working properly in connectivity. Please help, what to do?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-behind-a-proxy/

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution for this.

1.Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

> $ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

2.Create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf that adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:
(Use sudo touch/nano to create file)

> sudo nano filename.txt
>
> [Service]
>
> Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"

3.Flush changes:

> $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload

4.Restart Docker:

> $ sudo systemctl restart docker

5.Verify that the configuration has been loaded:

> $ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
>   Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/

visit : https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy